# The tilde key ("~") combination doesn't show up in bash

Tags: bash, keyboard, tilde

I am using an Acer Swift One laptop with Windows 10. The keyboard is a standard German keyboard.

I downloaded `bash` today from [git-scm.com/download/win](https://git-scm.com/download/win) and tried some commands. For some reason `bash` shows `k` instead of `~` when pressing the tilde key.

Any help or advice on what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Where/how are you running bash? (I mean - locally on a linux machine, through ssh/putty, etc.). This is most likely an issue outside of bash - keyboard layout, keybindings, etc.

Comment: I am using an acer swift one laptop with Windows 10.. How do I change the Keyboard layout to get the keys I need / which are showing on the physical keyboard. Well as I´m german the keyboard setting is on standard german. I tried to look up how to find the "virtual" keyboard layout but not successful.

Comment: Don't have much experience with DE layout, but according to wikipedia, tilde should be accessible via AltGr (right Alt) + the key with +, * on it, left of Enter.

If that fails, just add US-English layout a see if that helps. On that layout, tilde is on the key left of '1', via Shift.

Comment: This is a Win32 program running on Windows, and in an answer comment the questioner responded to a request for which Linux or Unix operating system this is, with "simply Windows 10".

Comment: There is no involvement of Unix or Linux here.

Comment: There is a way to get the key-press without interpretation. Press Ctrl-v and then the usual combination you use to get the tilde `~` and tell us what you get.

Comment: Is this the layout of your keyboard?  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/German_keyboard_layout  .... What it says is that you should use the Alr-Gr (the right Alt) to get the `~` from the key that is at the left of the `Enter`. Do you get a `k` when you press that in bash ?

Answer (score 0):

I'm using a Norwegian keyboard layout, and after doing this once, it for some reason works like normal again:

- Press <kbd>Alt Gr</kbd> + <kbd>^</kbd> twice.

[image: https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/566443/514949]]

Same as what Munzir Taha suggested in [his answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/566443/514949)

Comment: For reference / comparison, here’s an [image of the German keyboard layout](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Bnoz5.jpg), which I pulled from the [Wayback Machine](https://archive.org ""). (It was originally at http://www.uni-regensburg.de/EDV/Misc/KeyBoards/keys11l.jpg.)

Answer (score -3):

[This](https://bugs.freedesktop.org/show_bug.cgi?id=9752) could prove useful. It mentioned you need to press the key with <kbd>+*~</kbd> **twice**!

> On the german keyboard layout you have to hold "Alt Gr" and then type
>   the "+ * ~" key to create the tilde sign. When I want do do this in a
>   konsole that I opened with Xming, I have to type that  key two times
>   before the tilde appears

Comment: I just pressed the ctrl key and the key with +,* and ~ and bash shows a k. I don´t get it either because in all other tools I use i don´t have that issue with my keyboard

Comment: @Linda: Why do you need the ctrl key with +,* to type ~? Isn't the tilde in its own key to the left of the number 1 in your keyboard? I just need to press SHIFT with that key on the top left.

Comment: @Linda, can you please edit that into your question. And also specify which keyboard layout you have.  Are you sure about ctrl, I think you mean either shift or Alt Gr.

Comment: So I got a german keyboard on an acer swift one laptop.

Comment: The key contains +, * and ~ to get the + is only press the key +. To get * I press shift and + and to get the tilde i press Crtl, Alt and + = ~.. I mean this is working but somehow not in bash. MAybe I need to adjust the keyboard settings but I don´t know what should be set up then. I thought it would work right away :D

Comment: Which linux distribution and Desktop Environment are you using?

Comment: Simply windows 10.. https://git-scm.com/download/win this is the link where i downloaded the 64 bit version of bash

Comment: If you keep pressing Alt and then typed 126 would this help?

Comment: @MunzirTaha tried it before and it doesn´t help :(

Comment: @Linda: Alt-Gr and that button twice instead of one, works?

Comment: :O it does! Thanks!

Comment: @Linda: instead of voting the comment only, please, vote and accept the answer itself with the green check mark.

Comment: The bugs.freedesktop.org site links to this [image of the German keyboard layout](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Bnoz5.jpg), which I pulled from the [Wayback Machine](https://archive.org "").